# In app designer, how do I 'hold' my plot when switching between drop-down menu values?

Tags: matlab

In app designer, I have multiple drop-down menus that allow the user to select data values that are then plotted. The first time the 'plot' button is clicked, there are no issues with plotting only one selection from a menu, or plotting multiple data values from multiple drop-down menus. However, if the user changes a drop-down menu value, only one of the values is plotted unless the 'plot' button is clicked again.

I have tried multiple solutions, including using `hold` in various ways or by clearing the axis during the 'plot' button's initial run (e.g., by using `cla`) to essentially reset the 'plot' button function.

Sample code:

```
SelectedMetric = app.OsteoDropDown.Value;  
[ColumnValue] = OsteometricFunc(SelectedMetric);  


PopSelectionA = app.PopulationA.Value;  
[RowValue] = PopulationAFunc(PopSelectionA);  


x = 1:length(RowValue);  
y = OsteoData(RowValue,ColumnValue);  
%hold(app.UIAxes);  
scatter(app.UIAxes,x,y,'g');  

PopSelectionB = app.PopulationB.Value;  
[RowValue] = PopulationAFunc(PopSelectionB);  

x = 1:length(RowValue);  
y = OsteoData(RowValue,ColumnValue);  
hold(app.UIAxes);
scatter(app.UIAxes,x,y,'r');
```

First instance of clicking the 'Plot' button does everything correctly:
[image]

Second instance of clicking 'Plot' button, wherein only the drop-down for 'Population II' has been changed. The plot for 'Population I' is no longer visible, though it should be:

[image]

Clicking the 'plot' button again correctly plots all values, however:

[image]

How do I resolve this so that switching a single drop-down menu (or multiple drop-down menus, for that matter) automatically plot everything for all drop-down menu values?

Comment: Did you try calling the same callback you use for the "plot" button also in the drop-down menus? Then every time you change something, everything will be plotted anew.

Comment: That did not resolve the issue, unfortunately. However, I was able to get everything working properly by incorporating 'on' and 'off' into the `hold` statements, e.g., `hold(app.UIAxes,'on')` and `hold(app.UIAxes,'off')`